# How to make listview with clickable item as well as row

Tags: android, android-listview, row

I want clickable on item as well as click able on row of listview.in adapter I set clickable for some item.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `OnItemClickListener`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(ViewGroup parent, View v, int pos, long id){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.yes.i did so.but it still cannot clickable an row have highlight. it only is clicked some items .that i set clickable

Comment: edit your question and include the code that you are using to set your click listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout set like this for all the items...

```
 <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="" />
```

change the focusable and focusableintouchmode as shown..

Answer (score 0):

You can make parent layout with `onClick()` and all other child layout like textview or another else.

set `android:clickable="false"` all other child object.

If you find any trouble then let me know. put comment.